# DateTime Format user entries

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a method which will convert any format of `DateTime` a user enters. An example of an entry from the user can be `2Y 4M 3D` etc.
I need this entry to be converted to a duration like 2 years, 4 months and 3 days to be something like seconds.

Comment: What it the problem? do you want the code?

Comment: Yes i want something like a pseudo code. Where i can enter 2Y 4M 3D as entry and get duration.

Comment: "convert any format" - nigh on impossible unless the user is also telling you what format they're aiming for. Quick quiz - is `02/10/2015` a date in February or October?

Comment: Without giving away the code, I can tell you that you first need to parse the input string using something like Regex. Then you will need to use the TimeSpan struct which can be looked into here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: Give us what have you tried so far. Hint : use DateTime built-in methods.

Comment: The thing is the user is specifing the format when entering the values. I need just to parse it in a way and get the duration in the end.

Comment: **2 years 4 months and 3 days** from what ? This Year or the last year ? or the year prior to that ?

Comment: No you cannot prepare for a user's format...there are ambiguous formats like @Damien_The_Unbeliever shows so you cannot go about trying all formats because chances are more than one will match but not all will yield correct results.

Comment: How does the user enters this data? do you have a GUI in your application?

Comment: I need to find the time between  2 years 4 months and 3 days ago and now.

Comment: @AmatuerDev Ignore the Title. He is taking about Durations not Dates.

Comment: He enters the data in a Word doc.

Comment: I think he just wants to parse the input string as a duration in seconds.

Comment: Please edit your question with the relevant details. otherwise I'm afraid it will be closed as not clear very soon.

Comment: Yes this is what i want. But i need to be able to specify the input in this format: 2Y 4M 3D

Comment: Then use Regex as @JurgenCamilleri has said

Comment: Are you looking for TimeSpan or DateTime ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the user's input? do you know how to read it from the word document and get the relevant strings (i.e one for time span and one for format)? can the format really be anything? (i.e. 14/3/5 and d/m/y)?

Comment: The major problem I see with what you're doing is that the duration of for example 4M depends on which months you're talking about. Take for example January - April. In days it is usually 119, except that in a leap year it would be 120. Same goes for months which have 30 days versus those with 31.

Comment: The net library DateTime.Parse accepts a large variety of formats.  You can start with DateTime.ParseExact and then add your own custom parsing when ParseExact fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the total seconds. Try the following.

```
        var testString = "2Y 4M 3D";
        var splitString = testString.Split(' ');
        var year = int.Parse(splitString[0][0].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        var month = int.Parse(splitString[1][0].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        var day = int.Parse(splitString[2][0].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        var totalSeconds = (DateTime.Now.AddYears(year).AddMonths(month).AddDays(day) - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds;
```

[Heres a Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pFeJiL)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if I understand you correctly:

```
var sample = "2Y 4M 3D";
var split = sample.Split(' ');

DateTime prevDate, nextDate, now;
prevDate = nextDate = now = DateTime.Now;

foreach (var sp in split)
{
    var d = Regex.Match(sp, @"\d+").Value;
    var t = Regex.Match(sp, @"[A-Z]+").Value;

    switch(t)
    {
        case "Y":
            {
                prevDate = prevDate.AddYears(-int.Parse(d));
                nextDate = nextDate.AddYears(int.Parse(d)); 
                break;
            }
        case "M":
            {
                prevDate = prevDate.AddMonths(-int.Parse(d)); 
                nextDate = nextDate.AddMonths(int.Parse(d)); 
                break;
            }
        case "D":
            {
                prevDate = prevDate.AddDays(-int.Parse(d)); 
                nextDate = nextDate.AddDays(int.Parse(d)); 
                break;
            }
    }
}

var timeSpanPrev = now - prevDate;
var timeSpanNext = nextDate - now;
```